# Why is this nth-child returning an unexpected element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The html & jQuery is below and it's also at http://www.jsfiddle.net/4fWUU. I am expecting to get the second child of 'wrapper' which is the div with id 'parent2'. However the returned id is 'child1_1_1_2' which I don't expect.

I can get the proper div using `$o1.children()[1]` but I wanted to know why nth-child is not working right.

Any ideas why?

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="parent1">
            <div id="child1">
                <div id="child1_1">
                    <div id="child1_1_1">
                        <div id="child1_1_1_1">
                        </div>
                        <div id="child1_1_1_2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="child1_1_2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="child1_2">
                    <div id="child1_2_1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="parent2">
        </div>
    </div>


var $o1 = $("#wrapper");
var id = $("div:nth-child(2)",$o1).attr("id");

alert(id);
```

Comment: If you want only current children, `$("> div:nth-child(2)",$o1)` would be the way to go, or simpler: `$("#wrapper > div:nth-child(2)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching by context is the same as `.find()`, which picks up the deepest descendants *first* before traveling up the DOM tree. `:nth-child()` does not care about the parent if you don't specify a parent, thus every `div` that's contained by (is a child of) some other element of `#wrapper` or anything inside gets selected.

The `.children()` method, as it says on the tin, limits the selection to your element's children, so anything matched will always be a child. Use that instead but pass the `:nth-child()` selector like so:

```
var id = $o1.children('div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

Or as Nick Craver suggests, use the child selector `>` to limit your contextual search to children of `#wrapper`:

```
var id = $('> div:nth-child(2)', $o1).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

there are actually 4 instances of that selector:

```
var $o1 = $("#wrapper");
$("div:nth-child(2)",$o1).each(function () {
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```